# Multiple kubespray clusters in one inventory

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

[Kubespray](https://kubespray.io/) uses groups with defined names in Ansible inventory to specify roles of different nodes, and these nodes will connect to each other. But now I need two separate clusters (because each shall live in different subnet with different security policy). Is there a way to still keep one inventory with common definitions or do I have to split the inventory for the two clusters?

Comment: will your clusters  be the same except subnet and security policy? what other changes are you planning to have there?

Comment: @Vitalii, almost the same. One has ingress controller and the other has a flex volume driver that needs to be installed with an additional playbook (it requires some system packages).

Comment: … and the security policy does not affect the inventory at all, it's just a matter of the firewall that connects the network segments.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly don't recommend you to complicate things with kubespray and my advise is always use separate inventory files for different clusters. Using 1 inventory file could(and most probably) lead to additional errors and wasting your time trying to resolve them instead of simply spin 2 clusters from 2 files and use it. Btw, never saw such implementation. Surely, you can do it on your own, but do you really need it?

I would update this answer in case i find concrete resolution for you. Leaving it as community wiki